# Getting number of bytes read in zlib stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, zlib

I am using a `zlib.Inflate` to inflate a chunk of data. The problem I have now is that all I know is how many bytes of uncompressed data there are but not how many that is in the compressed stream. Im currently just writing the entire input buffer to the inflater and then read the amount of uncompressed bytes from it. That gives me the correct output data but I have to know how many bytes were consumed to continue parsing the remaining data.

So right now I did the following for testing:

```
    var inflater = zlib.createInflate();
    inflater.write(strm.buffer.slice(strm.position));
    inflater.on("readable", (function(inflater, len) {
        return function() {
            console.log(inflater);
            var decompData = inflater.read(len);
            console.log(inflater);
            var output = fs.createWriteStream("output.bin");
            output.write(decompData);
        }
    })(inflater, len));
```

I checked all members of the inflater before and after the read but nothing changes, every single value except the read buffer (with the decompressed data) is the same. Is there a way to determine how many bytes were read from the compressed buffer?

Thank you in advance, Cromon

Comment: I checked `node_zlib.cc` (0.10.2) and `zlib.js`. The C++ binding does not expose any member from the underlying `zstream` and only provides `availIn` and `availOut` after decompression to the `zlib.js`. There its only stored in a local variable to keep decompressing until the amount of data could be read. Using a custom input stream and a chunk size of 1 and then just count the amount of `_read` calls doesnt work because the minimum chunk size is 64. So I guess without any changes to one of the files (which is what I will do for now)

Comment: node.js should fix that.  They could do it similar to [python's zlib interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html), which has an `unused_data`  method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation of the C++ and JavaScript files involved in the zlib decompression module I realized these files all drop the information about how much of the data was read. Since the native `zlib`stream is not available to JavaScript its impossible to get the information about the amount of bytes consumed.

I changed `Zlib.prototype._transform` to check how many bytes were read and update a member in `Zlib` that holds the number of bytes consumed. With that it works like a charm: `stream.seek(inflater._consumed);`

This might not be of so much help except that it seems to me that its impossible to do this with the current layout of the zlib module.

Comment: Has anything changed in this regards lately?

Comment: I was able to make this work by using the `bytesWritten` property which is available since node v 10.